# How to print a series of rows in Java using an object's attributes?

Tags: java

Basically I have a student object stored in array list with attributes:

```
-firstName: String
-lastName: String
-studentID: String
-row: int
-column: int
```

now I want to print them in the console in such a way that it would look like this:

1st Row

studentID1 | studentID2 | studentIDn

firstName1 | firstName2 | firstNamen

lastName1  | lastName2  | lastNamen

2nd Row

studentID1 | studentID2 | studentIDn

firstName1 | firstName2 | firstNamen

lastName1  | lastName2  | lastNamen

The attributes come from a database and are stored in a student object. 
They are stored in such a way such that they are arranged according to column and row number. Now I want to print the above in such a way that when the row attribute changes it would print another "row" of students.

edit: what I did

```
   public void displayStudents() {
    studentListSize = StudentList.size();
    int listIndex = 0;                          // This variable gives you the size of the list
    int columnIndex = 0;                        // The column index gives you the column you are supposedly traversing
    int resetIndex = 0;                         // This index does what its name does which is essentially to reset a value
    int continueIndex = 0;                      // Index which tells one where one supposedly ended, hence the name 'continue'

    int currentRow = seats.get(columnIndex).getStudentRow();    // The currentRow method says which row one is currently traversing

    for(listIndex = 0; listIndex < seatSize; listIndex++) {
        // if the row attribute taken from the list of seats is not equal to the current row then, that means that the row has changed and 
        // the following loops execute 
        if(seats.get(listIndex).getStudentRow() != currentRow) {

            // The following methods just display stuff. It's essentially a looped version of the commented out method below
            System.out.println();
            for(columnIndex = resetIndex; columnIndex <= continueIndex; columnIndex++) {
                System.out.printf("|%10s|",  seats.get(columnIndex).getFirstName());
            }
            System.out.println();
            for(columnIndex = resetIndex; columnIndex <= continueIndex; columnIndex++) {
                System.out.printf("|%10s|",  seats.get(columnIndex).getLastName());
            }
            System.out.println();

        // setting the reset index to the column index is done because if you don't do this the for loops below will repeat the displayed things above with a new set of columns
        resetIndex = columnIndex;
        // this sets the currentRow
        currentRow = seats.get(listIndex).getStudentRow();
        // Print the IDs
        System.out.printf("|%10s|",  seats.get(listIndex).getStudentID());
        // the assignment below ensures that the all rows are printed (for the first set)
        continueIndex = listIndex;
    }

    // The next lines are workarounds which repeat what the above does. There could have been a better way had there been a functioning GOTO keyword in Java
    System.out.println();
    for(columnIndex = resetIndex; columnIndex <= continueIndex; columnIndex++) {
        System.out.printf("|%10s|",  seats.get(columnIndex).getFirstName());
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(columnIndex = resetIndex; columnIndex <= continueIndex; columnIndex++) {
        System.out.printf("|%10s|",  seats.get(columnIndex).getLastName());
    }
    System.out.println();
```

I repeated the code inside for the loop because it would only print up to the student ID of the second row.

The database was from mySQL and I just got the Result Set and basically Stored the Student objects in a LinkedList

Comment: Note that the output should be in the command line

Comment: What type of database? You didn't post any code at all. Please show us what have you tried first.

Comment: It looks like row 1 is actually 3 rows, and row 2 is exactly the same 3 rows. Huh?!?!?!

Comment: can you please clarify how you are storing student object in array list with attributes?

Comment: I made a Student Object with the attributes and stored them in a list.